# Application Settings in custom class ASP.Net 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Playing around with ASP.Net 5 MVC.  Seen this question jumping around but not an full answer.  What I want to do is have a helper class that is able to access the AppSettings.  I can access it in the controller and the view but haven't figured out how to access it on my own custom class.  Have startup configured like so.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    }
.................
.................
```

Answer (score 3):

So in your config.json file, suppose you have following settings

```
{
    "smtp": {
        "SenderEmail": "a@b.com",
        "SenderFrom": "Test User"
    }
}
```

Then in your ConfigureServices method you need to do something like that

`services.Configure<SmtpEmailSetting>(Configuration.GetSection("smtp"));`

This is your SmtpEmailSetting looks like

```
public class SmtpEmailSetting
{
    public string SenderEmail { get; set; }
    public string SenderFrom { get; set; }
}
```

and this is how you access your settings in any service or controller

```
public class SendEmailService
{
    private readonly SmtpEmailSetting _smtpEmailSetting;

    public SendEmailService(IOptions<SmtpEmailSetting> smtpOptions )
    {
        _smtpEmailSetting = smtpOptions.Value;
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        var fromEmail = _smtpEmailSetting.SenderEmail;
        var displayName = _smtpEmailSetting.SenderFrom;
    }
}
```

So basically you use your settings or options (whatever you prefer to call) should be used in constructor as a generic type parameter of `IOptions<>` class. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to access your AppSettings properties in your custom class, make configuration as a static instance such as:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
```

and make use of your AppSettings any where in your application (for connectionstring example) as:

```
var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to adeel41's answer, this is correct and works great, but for myself, I didn't want to drag around an IOption object when using dependency injection.

So I prefer to do something like

```
services.AddSingleton<ISmtpEmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SmtpSettings").Get<SmtpEmailSettings>());
```

Most importantly is the Get syntax added to GetSection to deserialize your JSON to an object.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of RC1, I took inspiration from [this post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/May/23/Strongly-Typed-Configuration-Settings-in-ASPNET-Core) by Rick Strahl, which worked great. That is very similar to other approaches already proposed.

This answer is just to update with my findings as of RTM release. It seems like `Configuration.GetSection(string topLevelKey)` does not work anymore, at least for me it always returns null (even if configuration sources are set correctly).

After some search, [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289751/asp-net-5-rc2-configuration-section-binding) pointed me in the right direction, by using:

```c#
// create empty config object
var smtpEmailSetting = new SmtpEmailSetting();

// fill it from configuration section
Configuration.GetSection("smtp").Bind(smtpEmailSetting);

// use it, e.g. by registering it into DI
services.Configure<SmtpEmailSetting>(smtpEmailSetting);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in your own class, it's probably right to pass it into the constructor of that class, or as a parameter. Eg;

```
public class Notifications
{
    public Notifications(AppSettings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public void SendEmail(string subject, string body) {
        SmptClient.Send(subject, body, settings["email address"]);
    }
}
```

So typically, you'd pass it through from your controller.

This avoids a global variable, which is always a good thing, I think.